# CSS and its inheritence

Tags: css, html-table

If I have a Table, and inside my style sheet I set a class or id to have a grey background. Then I use this ID or Class, will tr and td inherit these properties from the top? Or do I have to specify this for each tag.. Same for tr.. will td inherit properties of CSS from tr?

Comment: Why don't you simply try it?

Comment: this is very simple. you should just try it.

Comment: I did. And it wasn't working so I wanted to understand under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will inherit the background property the way you want it to.

Check it out in a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/46C7r/

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Stuff</td><td>Stuff</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Stuff</td><td>stff</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Stuff</td><td>stuff</td></tr>
</table>

table {background: grey;}
```

Answer (score 1):

tr and td will not inherit it, but will show it because tr and td are sitting within the table element. so it is the class of table being shown not class of tr and td.

If it was a font, tr and td would have inherited it.